# ClickOnce cannot install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and create database structure

Tags: windows-installer, clickonce, setup-deployment

ClickOnce is a great tool to create an installation file. But it cannot instal the MS SQL Server 2008 Express version, create an instance of my Database and run the database script.

I did a research about MSI, but it seems the latest version of MSI I can find is 4.5 which was released more than 2 years ago and I cannot instal in on my machine.

I also tried to use Microsoft Web Installer, it can be downloaded but I cannot use it to instal my project.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce is a web installer and for security reasons, it only install user profile components. SQL Server implies windows services that affect all users in that computer.